# How to compare count of columns with each other in group by groups and find the max of them

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sqlfiddle

At first please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b458/ for the database i have created. ( MYSQL)
Now i have a problem to FIND OUT IN WHICH COURSE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF STUDENTS HAVE TAKEN ADMISSION .
This is how i proceed

```
select course_name from `course-taken`
natural join course;

select course_name,count(course_name) from `course-taken`
natural join course
group by course_name;
```

Refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b458/6

Now the problem is how can i find the the maximum from the count(course_name)
I have tried with Max(count(course_name) [ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b458/7 ]
but that shows

> X Invalid use of group function

So can please anyone help me with correct query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: Including '-' anywhere within table/column identifiers is a recipe for absolute disaster.

Comment: The problem in question is solved. Thnx all. <br>But now if make the problem more difficult by FIND OUT IN WHICH COURSE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF STUDENTS HAVE TAKEN ADMISSION IN THIS MONTH.   i have already solved the problem on updated database - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/417e20 & quary http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/417e20/1 . So i want to know if i can do it more easily or can make this quary short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `HAVING` clause after the `GROUP BY` Clause to get the maximum course_name records

```
HAVING count(course_name) = ( 
                              SELECT max(maxc) FROM 
                         (
                           SELECT course_name, count(course_name) maxc 
                           FROM `course-taken`
                           NATURAL JOIN course
                           GROUP BY course_name)cnt
                         )
```

Comment: THANKS YOGESH YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM

Answer (score 0):

If you want the course with the maximum count, and there are either no ties for first, or you can tolerate returning a single record, then you can use `LIMIT` here:

```
SELECT course_name, COUNT(course_name) AS cnt
FROM course-taken
NATURAL JOIN course
GROUP BY course_name
ORDER BY COUNT(course_name) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: THANKS FOR UR HELP BUT I THINK YOGESH HAVE GIVE ME PERFECT ANSWER

Comment: @k.dot WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT ME?

Comment: SORRY , I HAVE NOT THAT INTENTION